# What are the tradeoffs, besides being more or less functional, in using a var List or val mutable.List

Tags: scala

I understand that the functional style prefers var or val List of a mutable, and I understand why, but I am thinking about purely time/space trade offs.

I am currently interfacing with a java library and have to write tons of non idomatic code in scala anyways..

Comment: I wrote some benchmark about time usage: http://p.streum.org/2012/02/benchmarking-scala-list-traversal-idioms/ and here is a followup by Benjamin Darfler: http://codedependents.com/2012/04/30/benchmarking-more-seq-traversal-idioms-in-scala/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe several pointers can help you to understand, why there is not a so big penalty when you use immutable structure:

- [The Performance characteristics table of the scala collections](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/performance-characteristics.html).
- [Extreme Cleverness: Functional Data Structures in Scala](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Functional-Data-Structures-in-Scala) (a quite long but so interesting video on immutable data structures)

Answer (score 2):

In my oppinon the greatest use of immutable List is, that there are no side-effects if you share them between objects. This is important if you start using concurency or even parrallelism.

By the way: Scala uses Builder to change existing Lists and 'recycles' the former List, so this is not as expensive as you might expect it to be.

**Edit**

As I got you now to get benchmarks I found [this](http://paradigmatic.streum.org/2012/02/benchmarking-scala-list-traversal-idioms/) one verry good, because they show the code they used.

Comment: Yes I understand why immutable Lists are preferred, but I am not writing beautiful idiomatic code in scala already, to interface correctly with some of these java libraries (slick2d and jbox2d) it already has to break a lot of idioms. I was wondering purely about performance.